# spliting string with double new line characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have a .txt file, the data of which I have stored in a long string. There are many single new line characters in the string after every line. And there are double new line characters at the end of paragraphs. What I want is to split the string into an array of paragraphs.

what I thought is the following but it is not working

```
string filePath = "C:\\Users\\Data.txt";
StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(filePath);
string Data = readFile.ReadToEnd();
string[] paragraphss = Regex.Split(Data, "(^|[^\n])\n{2}(?!\n)");
```

please help
thank you

Comment: How about... this: .Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On windows systems the newline character is `\r\n`, on Unix systems it is `\n`.  This may be why the lines aren't being split, because you're specifically looking for `\n\n` instead of `\r\n\r\n`.

You can however use `Environment.Newline`, which will return the correct newline character for whatever environment the software is running on.

Comment: thank you. What I was doing was splitting along \n\n but as I am on windows system I needed to look for \r\n\r\n. Thank you for your help.

Comment: That is not always true, that depends on the text editor used to save the document and how it is configured, some are crossplatform and will save them with \n as the default.

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with not using regex, `Data.Split("\n\n")` should do the trick.

Comment: it does not work string.split() only takes a chacater and not a string

Comment: Data.Split(new [] { "\n\n" }) then ;)

Comment: LueTm: There is no Split method that takes just a string array. Chaitanya, you can use a string array to split, if you use StringSplitOptions.None as second argument.

Answer (score -1):

Inspired by @LueTm's answer and @Traubenfuchs' comment, just making it look compiler friendly and complete. Here's how to split a string with double new line characters:

```
Data.Split(new string[] { "\r\n\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```